# ModuleNotFound error after using Pip to install a package in Anaconda virtual environment

Tags: pip, anaconda, juliacall

I'm using VSCode on a Mac, and I have set up an Anaconda virtual environment. Then I used Pip to install JuliaCall. However, upon running a .py file with just the line `from juliacall import Main as jl`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'juliacall'`.

I've used `which pip`, `which conda`, and `which python` to determine that I am indeed using the virtual environment's pip. In addition, I have gone into Finder and seen that there is a folder named juliacall in ~/anaconda3/envs/(env-name)/lib/python3.9/site-packages. Furthermore, the package shows up when I do `conda list` after `conda activate (env-name)`, and when I do `pip list`.

The package seems to have been successfully installed, but for some reason, when I try to use the package in a .py file, I get a ModuleNotFound error...